# Is there any Hindawi template for Cloud-Oriented Data Center Networking?

Tags: journal-publishing, journal

I need to rewrite my article to fit in the format of [Hindawi](http://hindawi.com) Special Issue Cloud-Oriented Data Center Networking. After searching their site, I can't really find any useful information about formatting, they only mention that pdfs and docs are accepted, nothing more, any LaTeX template is given. What should I do?

Comment: Are we talking http://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/guidelines/? If so, my feeling is they just want a manuscript, no specific formatting. However, the usual rule in such cases is to _ask the editorial office_: they after all make the decisions here.

Comment: @JosephWright♦:Yes, I asked about this journal. Ok, I will ask them, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing myself in regards to another of Hindawi's journals and so I wrote to them regarding whether any of their titles accept in submissions in `.tex` format and whether there are `.tex` templates which an author could use.

The response was timely and professional and I include elements of it here as the question regarding `.tex` templates is not addressed specifically on their website (*my italics*):

> A manuscript should be in PDF [or Word] format 
>   *regardless of the source file* from which the PDF was generated.
>
> We do not require authors to format their manuscript in any particular
>   way prior to submission. *There is no specific style file or Latex
>   format you should use.* 
>   ... [if accepted] our Production Department will
>   format it according to our in-house style.
>
> All tables and figures should be included in the PDF file of your
>   manuscript. ... all references
>   should be cited within the text.
>
> Our Manuscript Tracking System only allows for *one* file to be uploaded
>   as Supplementary Material ... [which may be] a Zip file containing all of your supplementary files.

In short, the Hindawi system appears to be unusually flexible.